# Music Player in C# Does Tot Play The Song I Added Later

Tags: c#

I made an mp3 player in C#. If I select the songs at once, they automatically play one after the other, but when it comes to a song I added later, I get a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" error. When I add music later, I want the song to play automatically one after the other, how can I do that?

```
string[] yol, dosya;
private void Btn_Muzik_Ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        dosya = ofd.SafeFileNames;
        yol = ofd.FileNames;
        for (int x = 0; x < dosya.Length; x++)
        {
            Lb_Muzik_Listesi.Items.Add(dosya[x]);
        }          
    }
}

private void Lb_Muzik_Listesi_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This Is Where I Got The Error
    OynatmaEkranı.URL = yol[Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex]; 
    OynatmaEkranı.Ctlcontrols.play();

    try
    {
        var file = TagLib.File.Create(yol[Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex]);
        var bin = (byte[])(file.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
        Pb_Muzik_Kapak.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin));
    }
    catch 
    {
             
    }
}

private void Zamanlayıcı_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Timer
{
    if (OynatmaEkranı.playState==WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        Pb_Muzik.Maximum=(int)OynatmaEkranı.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration;
        Pb_Muzik.Value = (int)OynatmaEkranı.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
        try
        {
            Lbl_Muzik_Sure.Text = OynatmaEkranı.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString;
            Lbl_Muzik_Bitis.Text = OynatmaEkranı.Ctlcontrols.currentItem
                .durationString.ToString();             
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
      
    if (Pb_Muzik.Value==Pb_Muzik.Maximum)
    {              
        if (Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex<Lb_Muzik_Listesi.Items.Count-1)
        {
            Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex = Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex + 1;              
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: In Btn_Muzik_Ekle_Click, you must clear your ListBox items or Add extra items to yol. Now, you add extra items to ListBox but not add extra items to yol, you are replacing yol array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this problem managing your data in the ListBox. Create a class with your required info (the file and the name):

```
public class MuzikItem
{
    public MuzikItem(string file)
    {
        this.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        this.Url = file;
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // This is the text to show in ListBox
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

Add items to the ListBox using this class:

```
foreach (var file in ofd.FileNames)
{
    var item = new MuzikItem(file);
    Lb_Muzik_Listesi.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And use it:

```
var item = Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedItem as MuzikItem;
if (item != null)
{
    OynatmaEkranı.URL = item.Url;
    OynatmaEkranı.Ctlcontrols.play();

    try
    {
        var file = TagLib.File.Create(item.Url);
        var bin = (byte[])file.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data;
        Pb_Muzik_Kapak.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

You try to get the selected item as a MuzikItem (all your items are of this class so this return null only when no item is selected) and with this, you have the Url.

**UPDATE**

I like manage this things with events. In your Ticks methods:

```
if (Pb_Muzik.Value == Pb_Muzik.Maximum)
{
    OnSongFinished();
}
```

And create a method to manage this event:

```
private void OnSongFinished()
{
    if (Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex < Lb_Muzik_Listesi.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex = Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Stop the player
        OynatmaEkrani.Ctlcontrols.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: So how can I stop the song when it reaches the final index? It still takes the last song of the playlist I added as the last index, and it doesn't take the song I added later as the last index. I used this                                                                                                                           if (Lb_Muzik_Listesi.SelectedIndex==Lb_Muzik_Listesi.Items.Count-1 & Pb_Muzik.Value==Pb_Muzik.Maximum)
            {
                OynatmaEkrani.Ctlcontrols.stop();
            }

Comment: I update my answer but your code seems ok.